Javascript errors shown as a fullpage on Visual Studio. How to disable?
So I am into React just lately and trying it on visual studio with a React app and C#. But it is a bit annoying that Javascript errors are shown as a full page instead of showing it on console.
Is there any way to disable this? I couldn't find a way of my own on and google did not help as it does not shows what I want

If this is duplicate, it woudl also help.
I am trying to have disabled Visual Studio runtime errors as full page instead of console.
I tried looking into Visual Studio, but I did not find anything and google it does not show that I am looking for.

This is a default set by the middleware which is used by the app template.

that has nothing to do with VS Code. the framework/library you're using shows error overlay

The problem you are facing isn't caused by VS Code, but by react itself
It isn't even a problem, it is just a way to let you know there is a problem with your code.
What you need to work on is your error handling to prevent your application from crashing as experienced by yourself.
Try making use of try and catch or .then().catch() for the block of code causing the error.
try {
    // Your code here
} catch (error) {
    // If an error occurs
    console.log(error); // shows the error in your console as message
    console.error(error); // shows the error in your console as an error
    alert(error);
    return error;

    // You can do whatever you want with the error here
}

doSomething()
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(error => {
    // If an error occurs
    console.log(error); // shows the error in your console as message
    console.error(error); // shows the error in your console as an error
    alert(error);
    return error;

    // You can do whatever you want with the error here
})


Thank you for the response. I know that is because of my own code that page response is runtime error. I am new to react and I am just playing around with react and few libs, though it is a bit obnoxius to reload the page and even more to handle exceptions. I ended up using try and catch. Thanks
